# How to get the user which added the discord bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to know the person which added the bot. How can I do this using discord.py?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend checking the [audit-log](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.audit_logs) via `guild.audit_logs()`. Discordpy does not explicitly include BOT_ADD, but it might be in there.

Otherwise you'll have to use the [official discord endpoint](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/audit-log#get-guild-audit-log) where you should see the `BOT_ADD` entry and the affected (executing) user.

Comment: can i see the code?

Comment: I usually only return code if there is code in the question. Otherwise I'll assume it's an explorative/conceptual question. Feel free to write another question if you have specific issues